# What is the important memory allocation flaw that is seen here?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Actually this was a homework I got. But I do not know the answer. Can anyone please help me?

What is the important memory allocation flaw that is seen in the following C++ code? How can you avoid it?

```
void testFunction(){
   int * p = new int(5);
   cout << p << *p << &p << endl;
}
```

Comment: You clearly put no effort into this. If you took 10 seconds to type in "C++ new" into google you would of immediately found advice about having one `delete` for every corresponding `new` and one `delete[]` for every corresponding `new[]` and not mixing them. Missing homework tag. Homework requires you to put in some effort, not to simply repost the question.

Comment: @Preet No need to take "that 10 seconds". I know that every new needs a delete and every new[] neds a delete[]. But the thing here is I did not understand the question. Thanks to Luchian Grigore, I understood the question properly only after reading his answer. And about the 'homework' tag; as I recently joined here, I did not know that there is a 'homework' tag. Anyway thanks for the information

Comment: I would presume that if you already "know" about `new` and `delete`, you would also have investigated what they actually do beyond syntax and have a basic idea of how they function (heap allocation), and hence how heap allocation differs from stack allocation/auto variables in usage and requirements. Might as well add here that in practical C++, you would almost never have a function like the one in the question (you would either use stack variable or pass a value in by reference or pointer if you need to modify it in the calling scope, or pass by value if you just want to print)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The memory is never released, so you have a memory leak. You can fix this by deleting the pointer:

```
void testFunction(){
   int * p = new int(5);
   cout << p << *p << &p << endl;
   delete p;
}
```